# set minimum or maximum number of tickets a person can buy

Tags: civievent

New to civiCRM so this might be an obvious one but I haven't found he answer as yet

I need to do 2 things with events:

- cap the number of tickets one given person can buy for an event. For example, set a limit of 2 tickets per transation, even though the event can be attended by 1500 persons.
- Set a minimum number of tickets to be bought. For example, you can buy group tickets if you're in a group of 10 or more. So the minimum number of tickets must be 10 but it can be 11, 12, 13, etc...

Thanks for your help!

Luke

Comment: Are you using Drupal? If so, selling your tickets via a Civi-Webform would offer you more flexibility and you could probably get creative with the form rules to provide these constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't functionality that CiviCRM offers "out of the box".  If you're a coder (or have access to one, or hire one from https://civicrm.org/providers) then you can add this functionality pretty easily with [hook_civicrm_validateForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) to create some custom validation rules.